# Java to UML generator on Linux

Tags: linux, gratis, java, uml

I want to generate UML class diagrams from my actual Java code. I used [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) when I had an academic License but as it is rather expensive I would like some recommendations.

**Required**

- See links between classes
- It allows me to modify the UML after generation (svg could work).
- Free, even for commercial use
- Linux

**Nice plus**

- **Does not depend on KDE** (has small dependencies)
- See which fields are linked from a class to another
- See links between packages
- Open Source
- Light weight (Visual Paradigm is terribly heavy and that was annoying sometimes)

I don't mind if it is an eclipse plugin or a standalone application.

**Follow up**

I tried [Umlet](http://www.umlet.com/) which I really liked for its lightness and speed but it does not show the links between classes and that makes it almost useless for me.

I tried papyrus as suggested but it does not do the expected work. At least if I have a lot of spare time some day I will know what project to work on.

Comment: related: [Generate UML Class Diagram from Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6167266/) on [SO]

Answer (score 3):

I had a need to do this a while ago, and I had the best outcome via [umlgraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/) .. by modifying the ant build files (in the javadoc section), you get UML diagrams generated for you whenever you do an ant-build of a target that includes javadoc.

Under the hood, umlgraph uses graphviz, so you will need graphviz installed but I am sure that will be in the standard repo of whatever distribution you are using.

I found [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u) really useful when I had to do this ..

**Some alternatives**

- [ydoc](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_ydoc.html) (from yworks) does a javadoc doclet .. functions similar to umlgraph in embedding SVG or flash based class (and other UML) diagrams  within generated javadoc files .. Unlike umlgraph, it is a full stand-alone GUI tool
- [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/) costs only $19 and was quite promising and very very useful.

I kept some notes of other tools (including some that are eclipse based plugins) .. and can dig them up, if you are interested in looking at some other alternatives.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution. I already used graphviz with doxygen and did not think of using it with javadoc. I'll give it a try as soon as I have some time for this.

Comment: @Johnride, yeah the blending into ant or maven build files is very useful.  However, given what you describe, ObjectAid seems like a perfect fit.  Seems they revised their license and you only need a license for sequence diagrams .. well, you can also get an evaluation license.  It is an eclipse plugin that reflects the changes (new code, refactoring) in your code within eclipse.   I really think you should look more closely at it.

Comment: [Here's objectaid's](http://www.objectaid.com/products) breakdown of what is free and what costs a little license fee .. together with the cost of their licenses.  Really agreeable.

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse Papyrus](https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/) project will allow you to do that. It works on Linux and is completely free.

I have used it a couple of times. It does the job but doesn't produce nice diagrams like the ones created in VS which look really cool.

There are a couple more options, some of them in this SO question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project

Comment: Guys, if you don't like the answer, tell why. Don't just secretly downvote it like some cowards. On a separate note, Papyrus didn't impress me. I've spend a day studying it and couldn't figure out how to turn the whole project to a UML. A UML of a single Java class is next to useless.