# UML to Java and Hibernate

Tags: java, database, uml

I want to design my UML diagrams in a program, and have the program generate Java classes and Hibernate mappings.

[Java to UML generator on Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/java-to-uml-generator-on-linux) is similar but does not fulfill all my requirements.

Required features:

1. Essentially drawing a class diagram and the program should generate the classes in Java.
2. Support UML [1.x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#UML_1.x) or [2.x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#UML_2.x)
3. The program must generate `*.java` files that work in Java 1.5.
4. The program generate `*.hbm.xml` files that work in Hibernate 4.
5. Must run in Windows or Linux (both is a plus).

Optional features:

1. Can export in other languages (like C# for example).

I tested [modelio](http://www.modelio.org/) but it is not for me.

Comment: If you have a lot of money - you could look at IBM Rational Software Architect with it's vast modelling and codegeneration abilities.

Comment: Eclipse has a UML plugin/extension that will generate code from your diagram

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use **[StarUML](http://staruml.io)**.

> **StarUML** is an open source project to develop fast, flexible, extensible, featureful, and freely-available UML/MDA platform running
>   on Win32 platform (from: [old project](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/v1) of StarUML, this project has
>   been discontinued). Although that project has been discontinued,
>   StarUML starts a new project (since long time no updates) with **StarUML
>   2**.

The newer version of StarUML almost fulfills your requirements below:

- You can [draw a class diagram](http://staruml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling-with-uml/working-with-class-diagram.html) and generate the classes in Java using [extension](https://github.com/staruml/Java).
- Compatible with UML 2.x standard and supports totally 11 kinds of UML diagrams. So, it must be different with UML 1.x.
- The program can generate classes in `*.java`, but it based on Java 1.7 specification
- The program can't generate `*.hbm.xml`.
- Running on Windows and Linux, even Mac OS X.
- (optional) you can generate source code not only for Java but also [C#](https://github.com/staruml/Csharp) / [C++](https://github.com/staruml/Cpp).

My answer can't fulfill your requirements. At least, it almost fulfills your needs. I hope my suggestion will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new, advanced Java code generator for StarUML, that also supports Hibernate (annotations), as well as Spring to a certain extent. For more information, you can visit https://www.archetypesoftware.com/.