# Class relationship "overviewer"/"explorer" for Java code

Tags: software-development, java, data-visualization

I'm looking for **a tool for rapidly visualizing structural relationships in Java code**.

The hard requirements are:

- generates structural diagrams of selected classes and packages,
- the diagrams are immediately visible in a viewer,
- the diagrams don't have to adhere to the UML spec, but have to be roughly recognizable as similar to class diagrams,
- relationships such as aggregation or inheritance should be shown,
- the user can relatively easily add/filter out classes and packages shown in the diagram,
- the tool should provide reliable autolayout for elements in the diagrams (no overlapping elements - this is something that e.g. [ObjectAid](http://objectaid.com/class-diagram) fails to accomplish),
- *if* the tool is *not* IDE-integrated, it should be aware of major dependency management systems (Maven, Ivy),
- it should be project-aware, and react reasonably quickly (sub-second on a good dev box, let's say) to changes in the code.
- it should be platform-independent (Linux/Windows/Mac).

Nice-to-haves are:

- IDE integration (Eclipse and/or IntelliJ IDEA),
- autolayout works well with manual adjustments done by the developer.

*Note that this is different from [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/java-to-uml-generator-on-linux) since it doesn't require on-line diagram generation, from [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/software-to-generate-class-diagram-from-java-source-not-dependent-on-eclipse) since Eclipse isn't anathema, and from both of them since it doesn't have to be actually producing UML and can be paid-for.*